# Definir un directorio para input type file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una aplicación web que genera un archivo txt, el cual es alojado en una carpeta predeterminada en el servidor, y lo envía mediante PHPmailer en forma automática. Por cuestiones de tener una segunda opción, agregué la funcionalidad de enviarlo manualmente mediante un form, también por PHPMailer. La duda me surge porque cuando se abre el explorador para elegir el txt, se muestran todas las carpetas del sitio. Si bien en el input type file filtro el tipo de archivo, quisiera saber si existe la forma de ocultar o impedir el acceso a las otras carpetas.

Comment: El directorio que se muestra siempre es el del cliente, no del servidor. ¿Cómo podría tener acceso un usuario al sistema de archivos en donde se ejecuta la aplicación? Lo que comentas es como decir que un usuario del sistema usa el servidor como su ordenador.

Comment: Tenés razón!!!!! Me acabo de dar cuenta!!!!! Que vergüenza, mi primera pregunta y me pasa esto. Perdón y mil veces perdón. Hay alguna forma en que pueda mandar el mail con un PHPmailer adjuntando el archivo que está alojado en el servidor entonces?

Comment: momento, te refieres a que puedan seleccionar un documento dentro del mismo sistema de archivos del lado del server? De ser cierto, podrías usar FTP con un usuario y contraseña validado por medio de sesión :D

Comment: Ya lo haces en el primer caso. Si tienes varios archivis y el usuario debe elegir, en lugar de un input file debes de listar los documentos mediante PHP y seleccionar uno, al seleccionar uno guardar en una variable la ruta de dicho archivo en el servidor.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que necesito hacer, me dí cuenta que estaba buscando la solución equivocada, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el archivo esta en el servidor y un usuario debe seleccionar un archivo a adjuntar entonces lo que debes hacer es listar los archivos de una determinada carpeta.

Puedes usar el siguiente script para lograrlo.

```
$directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{
    if (is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
    {
        echo "[".$archivo . "]<br />"; //de ser un directorio lo envolvemos entre corchetes
    }
    else
    {
        if (strpos($archivo,".txt") !== false)
        {
        echo $archivo . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Luego depende de ti con que forma se imprime los resultados. Si en un SELECT, en una lista desordenada, etc.

Yo limite que solo se impriman los archivo con formato .txt, pero puedes modificarlo o directamente quitarlo. Si no deseas que se impriman las carpetas debes usar el codigo asi.

```
$directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{
    if (!is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
    {
        if (strpos($archivo,".txt") !== false)
        {
        echo $archivo . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es justo lo que necesito.